# Count word frequency of huge text file

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, text-files, word-count

I have a huge text file (larger than the available RAM memory). I need to count the frequency of all words and output the word and the frequency count into a new file. The result should be sorted in the descending order of frequency count.

My Approach:

1. Sort the given file - external sort
2. Count the frequency of each word sequentially, store the count in another file (along with the word)
3. Sort the output file based of frequency count - external sort.

I want to know if there are better approaches to do it. I have heard of disk based hash tables? or B+ trees, but never tried them before.

Note: I have seen similar questions asked on SO, but none of them have to address the issue with data larger than memory.

Edit: Based on the comments, agreed the a dictionary in practice should fit in the memory of today's computers. But lets take a hypothetical dictionary of words, that is huge enough not to fit in the memory.

Comment: which programming language are you working on?

Comment: All different words still larger then RAM ?

Comment: if you just want to count words, you can read the file line-by-line or by file stream. You don't need to load the whole file into RAM.

Comment: @xvorsx: No single word is larger than RAM, if that is what your are asking.

Comment: How many _different_ words are there in the file? Would they fit in memory if you don't store duplicates?

Comment: Yes, the number of unique words is greater than the size of RAM. So if I have a hash table it would not fit in the memory

Comment: Really? How much RAM? Even a complete dictionary fits into today's computers RAM...

Comment: @vikky.rk The question was not if a single word will fit in memory but if the list of unique words will.

Comment: In practice yes the dictionary should fit, but say the dictionary if big enough not to fit in the memory, I want to know what approach would be better

Comment: Well, in that case ogzd gives a good answer below: slice it up!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would go with a `map reduce` approach:

1. Distribute your text file on nodes, assuming each text in a node can fit into RAM.
2. Calculate each word frequency within the node. (using `hash tables` )
3. Collect each result in a master node and combine them all.

Comment: Since the poster claims not even a dictionary of words used in the file fits into his tiny RAM(???) I vote +1 on THIS solution - and this also works when there's just one machine when you do the slices sequentially.

Comment: I thought about this approach sequentially, but how would I combine the results efficiently?

Comment: Sort each result file individually, then open them all and read line by line, deciding whether to add the results (same word) and/or, depending on sequence in alphabet, which word/nr pair to write to the result file.

Comment: Yes that is almost what external sort does. Except that we don't need to sort the entire file, just sorting the slices should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

All unique words probably fit in memory so I'd use this approach:

- Create a dictionary (`HashMap<string, int>`).
- Read the huge text file line by line.
- Add new words into the dictionary and set value to 1.
- Add 1 to the value of existing words.

After you've parsed the entire huge file:

- Sort the dictionary by frequency.
- Write, to a new file, the sorted dictionary with words and frequency.

Mind though to convert the words to either lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: nice approach. but would you sort the dictionary between every word? does that result in quicker search for future words?

Comment: no... Sort the dictionary after all words are added.

Comment: Why a `Dictionary`? The class is marked as obsolete.

Comment: @Matteo: I'm not suggesting to use the `Dictionary` class. Other than being obsolete it's also an abstract class and would be of no use. The choice of the word `dictionary` is based on what the `HashMap` is used for.

Comment: Assuming the majority of words are not duplicate. Will this approach work fine while reading the content of file size 1 Pebibyte (PiB)?

Comment: "probably fit in memory" bad assumption. In 2020 with 16GB or ram, I can't do this in memory (why I'm here).

Comment: @ldmtwo: You are not thinking correctly. Let's say the average word length is 8 letters. For simplicity we say 16 GB is 16 000 000 000 bytes. That would mean you could fit 2 000 000 000 **unique** words in memory. Do you know of a language with that many **unique** words? Even if the average word length would be 16 then you'd fit 1 000 000 000 **unique** words in memory. In comparison it has been estimated that the English language consist of roughly 1 000 000 **unique** words and I highly doublt all those are used in a written text in a file. (If it's not a complete word list that is).

Answer (score 3):

Best way to achieve it would be to read the file line by line and store the words into a Multimap (e.g. [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap)). If this Map extends your memory you could try using a Key-Value store (e.g. Berkeley JE DB, or [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB)). These key-value stores work similar to a map, but they store their values on the HDD. I used MapDB for a similar problem and it was blazing fast.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of unique words and the frequency fits in memory (not the file just the unique words) you can use a hash table and read the file sequentially (without storing it).

You can then sort the entries of the hash table by the number of occurrences.